# Servicenow UI Policy Script to reference fields pulling data from referenced field

Tags: servicenow

I am trying to find a way to create a UI Policy script that will reference other field in a project (name and description) from the above defined parent field. The parent field is a reference field, so the dropdown icon to the right of the text is working. I would like to learn how to have additional reference fields that reference other data field within the defined Parent field.

I am new to this, so any help would be appreciated. This is the script I have put together thus far.

```js
function onCondition() {
  var x = g_form.getReference('parent');
  g_form.setValue('u_prj_short_desc', x);
  g_form.setValue('u_prj_desc', x);
}
```

[image]

Comment: So you need to copy both of the name and description fields from the parent project to the current one, and that should happen each time the parent project changes? right?